# Bitmap.getPixel(x, y)'s RGB methods return slightly different values on different devices

Tags: java, android, colors, bitmap

```
ImageView colors;
Bitmap bitmap;
...
//onTouch:
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
    colors.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors.getDrawingCache());
    colors.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    int touchedColor = bitmap.getPixel(evX, evY);
    int red = Color.red(touchedColor);
    int green = Color.green(touchedColor);
    int blue = Color.blue(touchedColor);
    ...
}
```

Here's the issue: On a Samsung Galaxy S8 when you click this one color touchedColor is equal to -831953. On a Moto Z2 Play it is -897230 and the same is true on every emulator on Android Studio. This is when you click on the exact same pixel location on the image on both phones and each emulator. The bitmap that is in colors comes from the drawable-nodpi folder and is a PNG.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer myself: The answer is that png images show up differently on different devices. Use a bmp image.

RGB is device dependent using png images: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-ColorAppendix.html

BMP was designed to have RGB be device independent

Comment: Could you please provide some source on why are they processed differently?

Comment: where you getting the PNG?